# Bash Script to Edit MongoDB config file

Tags: mongodb, bash, shell, ubuntu-16.04

I want to replace bindIp : 127.0.0.0 with bindIP: 0.0.0.0 using bash script while installation.
Can someone tell me how to do this via bash?

Part to Edit:

```
    # network interfaces
 net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.0
```

Replace **127.0.0.0 with 0.0.0.0**

Command i am using:

```
sed '0,/bindIp:*;/s//bindIp: 0.0.0.0;/' /etc/mongod.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed "s,\\(^[[:blank:]]*bindIp:\\) .*,\\1 0.0.0.0," /etc/mongod.conf
```

if you want to edit the file on the fly, use the option `-i`

```
sed -i "s,\\(^[[:blank:]]*bindIp:\\) .*,\\1 0.0.0.0," /etc/mongod.conf
```

Comment: I am getting error : "sed: couldn't open temporary file /etc/sedm01lM0: Permission denied"

Comment: That's because you are not root, not because anything is wrong with the `sed` command.

Comment: ... Or possibly you are inside Docker which sometimes acts super weird with some system locations.

Comment: Using single quotes instead of double would allow you to change the double backslashes to single.

Comment: @RahulAnand Yes, as @tripleee's explain, maybe you need `sudo` to run this command. `sudo sed -i "s,\\(^[[:blank:]]*bindIp:\\) .*,\\1 0.0.0.0," /etc/mongod.conf`.